# Given offsets, adding span to a text string using javascript

Tags: javascript

I have string, call it s that contains some text, say

```
var s = 'The cat in the hat';
```

I know that 'cat' starts at 4 and ends with 6. What is the best way to add the span so that I end up with

```
'The <span id='myid'>cat</span> in the hat.'
```

Is there some HTML dom parsing magic machine that does this well?  Assume that I start with plain text. Links to duplicate answers would be much appreciated too.

**Update** Note that I might have more than one span that I have to insert. So I have to somehow remember the original string to put it back together. For example, consider I have coordinates to insert spans for 'hat' as well.

**Update2** There have been quite a few substitution-type solution, I want to emphasize, that I start with offsets, for example

[[4, 6], [16, 18]] to add spans to.

Answer (score 0):

You could use [`String#replace`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace):

```
var s = 'The cat in the hat';
var keywords = ['cat', 'hat'];

for (var i=0; i < keywords.length; i++) {
    s = s.replace(keywords[i], '<span>$&</span>');
}

console.log(s); // The <span>cat</span> in the <span>hat</span>
```

Comment: @Tooraj No, only the first of each. You need to use the global flag to replace all: `s = s.replace(new RegExp(keywords[i], 'g'), '<span>$&</span>');`

Comment: And in case of replacing second 'cat'?

Comment: Btw, I will already have the locations of each word, e.g., 4-6, but don't know what the words are.

Answer (score 0):

Try to replace like this...

```
var s = 'The cat in the hat'
s.replace(s.substring(4,7),'<span id="myid">' + s.substring(4,7) + '</span>');
```

**OR**

To replace both **'cat'** and **'hat'**
use as follow:

```
var s = 'The cat in the hat';
var arr = ['cat', 'hat'];

for (var i=0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    s = s.replace(new RegExp(arr[i],"g"),'<span id="myid">' + arr[i] + '</span>');
}
```

Comment: And in case of replacing second 'cat'?

Comment: Or the hat?  This is looking more and more yucky as I think about it.

Comment: @Tooraj to replace all cat in the string use the following code:
`s.replace(/cat/gi,'<span id="myid">' + 'cat' + '</span>');`

Comment: you can also use like this:
`s.replace(new RegExp(s.substring(4,7),"g"),'<span id="myid">' + 'cat' + '</span>');`

Answer (score -1):

On there way is,

```
var s = 'The cat in the hat';
var newStr = '';
​var strArr = s.split(" ");
for (i=0;i<strArr.length;i++){
    alert(strArr[i]);
    if(strArr[i] == 'cat'){
        newStr  += ' <span>' + strArr[i] + '</span>';    
    }else{
            newStr  += ' ' + strArr[i];
    }       
}
alert(newStr);
​
```

Try this [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vrW2n/25/)

Comment: Incorrect solution because the question mentioned that the position is given and not the keyword. Meaning we know we have to add a span on position 4, we don't know there's a word cat.

Comment: This is very generic answer for any string having word cat at any place. this answer is not Incorrect as it produce expected result with different remedy.